# How to debug what is setting dom element style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Something is setting every `li` elements style to `opacity:1;display:list-item`.
Is there any method to debug which part of javascript is doing this?
I am using Chrome...

Comment: *random guess* Are you calling jQuery `.show()` on them?

Comment: Well it is possible - my item is added by Chaplin Collection View (Chaplin.js is extension of Backbone.js) so it is likely it performs `.show()` on item - but why `display: list-item` is added? I want to avoid this...

Comment: YOu can debug this with the chrome dev tools - Profiles tab.. click start, when the unwanted behavior happens, press 'stop'.. then sift through the functions and find out who ran the operation..

Comment: I am not so quick to press stop XD. anyway @Niet s comment helped me - I found out that jquery sets automatically display to default item display if show/hide method is called on element which is not attached to dom yet. I ended up with setting display to whatever I want just before item is attached to dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Niet scores +1 to random guess successes!

Those particular items are added when jQuery's `.show()` method is called. It uses the tag name (in this case, `<li>`) to determine what the default style should be and sets it.

However, if you overrode it in CSS for example, you may want to use `!important` to continue overriding the `display:list-item`. However, keep in mind that this will prevent you from setting `display:none` on them if you decide to do so (such as jQuery `.hide()`).